# count the number of items before a class jquery

Tags: jquery, count, carousel, flexslider

I have a really basic jquery carousel that outputs this code:

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><a>red</a></li>
        <li><a>green</a></li>
        <li><a class="flex-active">blue</a></li>
        <li><a>black</a></li>
        <li><a>white</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="count"></div>
```

I want to output the current slide number (slide 3 of 5) but using .index() doesn't seem to work. It keeps coming up as "-1" and won't update as the carousel slides.

```
var total = $('.carousel li').length;
var current = $(this).find('.flex-active');

$("#count").html($('li').index(current)  + ' of ' + total);
```

example:
http://files.marksy.com/public/slider/index.html

Comment: what is `this`? Inside what event/function are you calling this javascript?

Comment: Also, you are looking for the index of an `a` tag, which I assume isn't in the list anyway. maybe try `$(this).find('.flex-active').parent()` to get the current `li` element

Comment: Have you tried: var current = $(this).find('.flex-active').parent()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all a bit jumbled, $(this) isn't what your after, also you're finding a child of the li's so it's index will be wrong, need to get it's parent.  I've cleaned it up a tad.

http://jsfiddle.net/jozzhart/uMNvB/

```
var $slides = $('.slides li');
var $current = $slides.find('.flex-active').parent();

var index = $slides.index($current) + 1;
var total = $slides.length;

$("#count").html(index + ' of ' + total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maby something like this to output:

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul id="flex-UL" class="slides">
        <li><a>red</a></li>
        <li><a>green</a></li>
        <li id="flex-active"><a>blue</a></li>
        <li><a>black</a></li>
        <li><a>white</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="count"></div>
```

Its bether workable

Than:

```
var listItem = $('#flex-active');
var listTotal= $("#flex-UL li").size()
$('#count').html( 'Index: ' + $('li').index(listItem) + ' / ' + listTotal);
```

Output:

```
red
green
blue
black
white
```

Index: 2 / 5

Answer (score 0):

In your example you're using *FlexSlider*.

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({animation:"slide"});
```

FlexSlider stores the current slide number and you can use the `after`-callback to get the this value:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide", 
    after: function(slider) {
        alert (slider.currentSlide);
    }
});
```

You can read more about it in the documentation. It's in the "*Advanced*"-tab and starts at "[The new, robust Callback API](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)".

Answer (score 0):

O And for your setup:

```
   var listItem = $(".flex-active").parent();
   var listTotal = $(".slides li").size();
   var listitemNow = $('li').index(listItem);
   listitemNow++;
   $('#count').html('Index: ' + listitemNow + ' of ' + listTotal);
```

Output:

```
red
green
blue
black
white
```

Index: 3 of 5